# How to hide array of div on esc keypress in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have `array` of popup div tags in my project. I have to hide the particular div which is popped up using for loop. Here is the JavaScript code:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var TargetDiv = document.getElementById('Srt_pgina');
    var PopupDiv = document.getElementById('pgina');
    var PopupTagContent = document.getElementById('PopupTagContent');
    var SearchFormDiv = document.getElementById("sf-search-form");
    if (e.keyCode == 27) {
        var Popup = new Array();
        Popup[0] = TargetDiv;
        Popup[1] = PopupDiv;
        Popup[2] = PopupTagContent;
        Popup[3] = SearchFormDiv;
        for (var i = 0; i < Popup.length; i++) {
            if (Popup[i].style.display == 'block') {
                Popup[i].style.display = 'none';
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: `Popup[0] = TargetDiv;` these aren't setting `Popup[x]` to any document element objects. They are just assigning whatever string you got from the `.value` assignments above. You should be seeing errors in your Dev Tools console

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 27) { 
       $('#Srt_pgina').hide();
       $('#pgina').hide();
       $('#PopupTagContent').hide();
       $('#sf-search-form').hide();
   }
});
```

This is the jQuery code for your javascript code.